# Angular 2 unit test error Unable to get property 'preventDefault' of undefined or null reference

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-cli

I created a bunch of unit tests for a component that I have. It was originally failing because I got the above error, so I took out the event.defaultPrevented stuff without actually knowing what it was doing.

Well, that fixed my errors, but obviously had a really bad side-effect on the UI behavior, so I had to put that stuff back in my code.

So, now I'm back to fixing my unit tests. How am I able to mock/inject the Event stuff into my unit tests?

Just the default 'should create' test that is stubbed out by Angular CLI is failing, here's the code:

```
let component: MemberAddComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MemberAddComponent>;
let contractsService: ContractsService;
let notesService: NotesService;
let saveButton: any;

beforeEach(async(() => {
    let router = { navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate') };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            HttpModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            RouterTestingModule
        ],
        declarations: [
            MemberAddComponent,
            // lots more here
        ],
        providers: [
            AppDataService,
            ErrorService,
            {
                provide: ContractsService,
                useClass: MockContractsService
            },
            {
                provide: NotesService,
                useClass: MockNotesService
            }
        ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MemberAddComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    contractsService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ContractsService);
    saveButton = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#saveButton');
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

And here's the ngOnInit function which should be the only thing running for this test:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.log('ngOnInit', 'ngOnInit...');

    this.routeSubscription = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.memberId = params['id'] || null;
        this.effectiveDate = params['from'] || null;
        this.cancelDate = params['to'] || null;
        this.group = params['group'] || null;
        this.subgroup = params['subgroup'] || null;
    });

    this.contractRequest = new models.AddContractRequestUI();

    this.dataservice.effectiveDateOfChange = this.dataservice.getCurrentDateMountainTimezone();
    this.dataservice.todaysDateString = this.dataservice.effectiveDateOfChange;

    if (this.contractRequest.subscriber.class.length === 0) {
        this.contractRequest.subscriber.class.push(new models.AddContractRequestSubscriberClass(this.dataservice.effectiveDateOfChange));
    }

    this.loadContractDetails();

    this.dependent.originalEffectiveDt = this.dataservice.effectiveDateOfChange;
    this.memberComplete = false;
    this.transactionStartTime = new Date();
}
```

Edit: notice there isn't the `event.preventDefault` or `event.defaultPrevented` anywhere in the code that is being tested. That only exists on the `onSubmit` function for the post/submit process on that component. But yet it's still making the unit test fail.

Edit2: Here's the html page, as well as the onSave() function

Html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div *ngIf="!waiting" class="row mb-20">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <a class="link-icon" (click)="onClickBack()">
                <span class="icon-wmkCaretLeft"></span>
                <span class="link-text text-uppercase text-condensed">Back</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <form *ngIf="(!loadError)" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSave()">
                <template [ngIf]="groupComplete">
                    <wm-groupinfo-view [groupName]="contractRequest.groupName" [groupId]="contractRequest.groupIdentifier" [subgroupId]="contractRequest.subgroupIdentifier"></wm-groupinfo-view>
                </template>
                <template [ngIf]="groupComplete && !effectiveDateComplete">
                    <member-add-effective-date [componentTitle]="enterEffectiveDateTitle" [effectiveDateString]="dataservice.effectiveDateOfChange" (complete)="onEffectiveDateComplete($event)"></member-add-effective-date>
                </template>
                <template [ngIf]="groupComplete && effectiveDateComplete">
                    <h3 class="text-uppercase">Effective Date</h3>
                    <p><span class="field-label">Effective Date of Change: </span>{{ dataservice.effectiveDateOfChange | wmFixDateFormat }}</p>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onClickEditEffectiveDate()">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                            Edit Effective Date
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </template>
                <template [ngIf]="effectiveDateComplete">
                    <member-add-subscriber-info [member]="contractRequest.member[0]" [subscriberId]="memberId" (complete)="onSubscriberInfoComplete($event)"></member-add-subscriber-info>
                </template>
                <template [ngIf]="subscriberDemoComplete">
                    <template [ngIf]="!homeAddressInfoComplete">
                        <member-add-subscriber-address [address]="homeAddressObject" (complete)="onAddressInfoComplete($event)"></member-add-subscriber-address>
                    </template>
                    <template [ngIf]="homeAddressInfoComplete">
                        <h3 class="text-uppercase">Subscriber Home Address Information</h3>
                        <p *ngIf="dataservice.selectedContract.address[0].type === 'Primary'"><strong>Address Type: </strong>HOME</p>
                        <p *ngIf="dataservice.selectedContract.address[0].type !== 'Primary'"><strong>Address Type: </strong>MAILING</p>
                        <p><strong>Address Line 1: </strong>{{dataservice.selectedContract.address[0].addressLine1}}</p>
                        <p><strong>Address Line 2: </strong>{{dataservice.selectedContract.address[0].addressLine2}}</p>
                        <p><strong>City: </strong>{{dataservice.selectedContract.address[0].city}}</p>
                        <p><strong>State: </strong>{{dataservice.selectedContract.address[0].state}}</p>
                        <p><strong>Zip Code: </strong>{{getZipString(0)}}</p>
                        <p><strong>County: </strong>{{dataservice.selectedContract.address[0].county?.description}}</p>
                        <p><strong>Email: </strong>{{dataservice.selectedContract.address[0].email}}</p>
                        <p><strong>Phone Number: </strong>{{ dataservice.selectedContract.phoneNumber | wmPhonePipe }}</p>
                        <div class="buttons">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onClickEditAddressInfo()">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                                Edit Subscriber Home Address
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <template [ngIf]="!showMailingAddress">
                            <div class="buttons">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onClickAddMailingAddressInfo()">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-add"></i>
                                    Add Subscriber Mailing Address
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </template>
                        <template [ngIf]="showMailingAddress">
                            <template [ngIf]="!mailingAddressInfoComplete">
                                <member-add-subscriber-address [address]="mailingAddressObject" (complete)="onMailingAddressInfoComplete($event)" (delete)="onClickDeleteMailingAddressInfo($event)"></member-add-subscriber-address>
                            </template>
                            <template [ngIf]="mailingAddressInfoComplete">
                                <h3 class="text-uppercase">Subscriber Mailing Address Information</h3>
                                <p *ngIf="dataservice.selectedContract.address[1].type === 'Primary'"><strong>Address Type: </strong>HOME</p>
                                <p *ngIf="dataservice.selectedContract.address[1].type !== 'Primary'"><strong>Address Type: </strong>MAILING</p>
                                <p><strong>Address Line 1: </strong>{{dataservice.selectedContract.address[1].addressLine1}}</p>
                                <p><strong>Address Line 2: </strong>{{dataservice.selectedContract.address[1].addressLine2}}</p>
                                <p><strong>City: </strong>{{dataservice.selectedContract.address[1].city}}</p>
                                <p><strong>State: </strong>{{dataservice.selectedContract.address[1].state}}</p>
                                <p><strong>Zip Code: </strong>{{dataservice.selectedContract.address[1].zip}}</p>
                                <p><strong>County: </strong>{{dataservice.selectedContract.address[1].county?.description}}</p>
                                <div class="buttons">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onClickEditMailingAddressInfo()">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                                        Edit Subscriber Mailing Address
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onClickDeleteMailingAddressInfo()">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                                        Delete Subscriber Mailing Address
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </template>
                        </template>
                    </template>
                </template>
                <ng-container *ngIf="subscriberDemoComplete && homeAddressInfoComplete && (!showMailingAddress || mailingAddressInfoComplete)">
                    <member-add-dependent *ngIf="addingDependents" [member]="dependent" [editing]="isEditingDependent" (complete)="onDependentComplete($event)"></member-add-dependent>
                    <div *ngIf="dependentComplete">
                        <h3 class="text-uppercase">Dependent/Member Information</h3>
                        <p><strong>Relationship: </strong>{{ dataservice.getRelationshipString(dependent.relationship) }}</p>
                        <p><strong>First Name: </strong>{{dependent.firstName}}</p>
                        <p><strong>Middle Initial: </strong>{{dependent.middleInitial}}</p>
                        <p><strong>Last Name: </strong>{{dependent.lastName}}</p>
                        <p><strong>Title: </strong>{{dependent.title}}</p>
                        <p><strong>Date of Birth: </strong>{{ dependent.birthDt | wmFixDateFormat }}</p>
                        <p><strong>Social Security Number: </strong>{{dependent.ssn}}</p>
                        <p><strong>Gender: </strong>{{dependent.sex}}</p>
                        <p><strong>Marital Status: </strong>{{dependent.maritalStatus}}</p>
                        <p><strong>Original Effective Date: </strong>{{dependent.originalEffectiveDt | wmFixDateFormat}}</p>
                        <div class="buttons">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onClickEditDependentDemo(dependent)">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                                Edit Dependent Information
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container *ngIf="showProducts && dependentComplete">
                    <member-add-products [members]="contractRequest.member" [addingMember]="true" (complete)="onProductsComplete($event)"></member-add-products>
                </ng-container>
                <div>
                    <wm-error-list [errors]="errorList" (clickError)="focusField($event)" (addError)="errorAdded($event)"></wm-error-list>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="(!waiting)" class="buttons pb-10">
                    <div *ngIf="canSave()">
                        <button id="saveButton" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Add&nbsp;Member</button>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="!canSave()">
                        <button [disabled]="true" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Add&nbsp;Member</button>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary pull-right" type="button" (click)="onClickCancel()">Cancel</button>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="(waiting)">
                    <wm-spinner></wm-spinner>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div *ngIf="(loadError)">
                <h3>{{errorMessage}}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

onSave():

```
onSave() {
    if (event.defaultPrevented || this.waiting) {
        return;
    }

    this.clearErrors();
    this.checkErrors();

    if (this.hasErrors() || (!this.unitTesting && !confirm("You are about to add this member. Are you sure you want to continue?"))) {
        return;
    }

    this.waiting = true;

    this.saveUpdatedSubscriberInformation();

    var addMemberObject = this.buildAddMemberObject();

    this.contractsService.addMember(addMemberObject)
        .subscribe(response => {
            this.parseAddMemberResponse(response, addMemberObject, true);
            //only save the note on success of adding member
            this.saveNote();
        }, error => {
            this.parseAddMemberResponse(error, addMemberObject, false);
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a plunker?

Comment: html of form and onSubmit code, could be helpful

Comment: @valorkin I updated the question with the html and onSave code.

Comment: @yurzui I'm still trying to figure out out to get the Plunkr setup.

Comment: You can start with https://plnkr.co/edit/mRiurK3ETRONx2Lp46KN?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working awhile ago, but I forgot to update my SO question...

All that needed to be done was create a dummy "event" object on my component, then explicitly set some values in the test prior to running everything. Once that was done, everything was working fine.

So, doing something like this could have worked in the component:

```
if (event && event.preventDefault) { event.preventDefault(); }
```

Or this could have been done in the test:

```
component.event = { preventDefault: function () {} };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent your event you will have to add the event to your onSave function, so replace

```
<form *ngIf="(!loadError)" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSave()">
```

with

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" *ngIf="(!loadError)" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSave(myForm, $event)">
```

and add the parameters to the OnSave function

```
public onSave(myForm: any, event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // or event.defaultPrevented to check
    .... rest of your code
}
```